# Persist Changes to auto-generated DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm currently trying to find a elegant way to allow changes to be made to a connection string set in the constructor of my DbContext.  Below is the current Auto-generated code which I added `this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"ConnectionStringToPersist";`
 to be able to edit the connectionString.

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{

    public DbEntities()
        : base("name=DbEntities")
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"ConnectionStringToPersist";
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Log> Log { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Processed> Processed { get; set; }
}
```

The initial goal was to move my connectionString outside of my app.config, so I decided to try to set it this way (and it works) - but if I were to ever add/remove/modify a table the change I made to the connection string would be overwritten on regeneration.

Is there a better way to use connectionStrings within my code?  The initial reason for moving the connectionStrings outside of the app.config was to remove the possibility of credentials sitting in the config files.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can use `base(@"ConnectionStringToPersist")`. But any decompiler can read the connection string! There are ways to encrypt connection strings.

Comment: @GertArnold I've found ways to encrypt it, but the process is annoying if I'm installing the application on another machine, or If I have to go back and de-crypt, change, encrypt.  Wouldn't your change still be deleted on regeneration?

Comment: Well, security *is* annoying. Nobody really likes it. Anyway, you can also create a partial class, beside the generated class, with a second constructor accepting the connection string, so you can supply it in a context factory, for example. I don't consider this safe though for reasons I mentioned above.

Comment: @GertArnold What would be best practice for keeping credentials within a connection string then?

Comment: Never did it, but google "encrypt connection string c#" gives enough hits.

Comment: @GertArnold Yeah - I figured that way out yesterday, but it has it's own annoyances :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using `aspnet_regiis` and encrypting the `connectionStrings` section of your app.config (before trying to do this - your app.config must be renamed to web.config).

Create a new class and declare a partial class of `Entities`

```
public partial class Entities
{
    public DbEntities()
        : base(@"ConnectionStringToPersist")
    {

    }
}
```

Then remove/comment out the original definition for the constructor in the auto-generated class, and it should work as expected.  This is what I have come up with so far, but I'll keep looking for different ways to approach this problem.

This still doesn't solve the problem of entity regeneration though - so still looking into that.